# Differential equation $(1-x)(y')^2+(y-x)y'+y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

I have the following problem.

Find all differentiable on $[0,1)$ non-negative functions $f$, for which for any $u\in(0,1)$ the tangent line to graph of $f$ in the point $(u,f(u))$ intersects the lines $y=0$ and  $x=1$ in the points $A$ and $B$ respectively and $x_{A}=y_{B}$. Also, $f'(0)=0$.

Easy to show that our function it's a root of the equation $$y=xy'-\frac{y'^2}{1+y'}$$ or
$$(1-x)(y')^2+(y-x)y'+y=0.$$
My question: is there some way to solve this equation directly?

Also, I assumed that the graph of $f$ is parabola with focus $F\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and directrix $y=x-1,$ which gives an equation of the parabola: $$(x+y)^2=4y,$$ which gives a solution of our equation.

My second question: is there some better way to get this parabola?

Thank you!

Comment: That curve is not an ellipse but a parabola.

Comment: Yes, I am mefager. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: $$y=xy'-\frac{y'^2}{1+y'}$$
This is Clairaut's differential equation.

Comment: here is [solution](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/june_8_2023.pdf) to the ode found on the internet

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there some better way to get this ellipse?" I don't know if the following methods are better or not, anyway here they are.

[The focus of a parabola lies on the circumcircle of the triangle formed by any three of its tangents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687260/find-the-parabola-tangent-to-4-given-lines/4687444#4687444). The circumcircles of the right triangles formed by lines $y=0$, $x=1$ and $AB$ all pass through point $F=(1/2,1/2)$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691104/the-area-between-parabolic-lines-inside-a-square/4691225#4691225) for more details), hence line $AB$ is tangent to the parabola with focus $F$ and also tangent to $y=0$, $x=1$. By symmetry, the axis of that parabola must be the line passing through $F$ and $T=(1,0)$ and its directrix passes through $T$ (because perpendicular tangents of a parabola meet on the directrix). This proves that an arc of that parabola is a solution of your equation.

Another method: the curve you are looking for is the envelope of the lines passing through $A=(t,0)$ and $B=(1,t)$, whose equations are
$$
y(1-t)=tx-t^2.
$$
We can then follow the usual procedure to find the equation of the envelope: differentiate the above equation with respect to $t$, solve the resulting equation for $t$ and substitute back the result into the above equation: the final result is exactly the cartesian equation of the parabola found above.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-x)(y')^2+(y-x)y'+y=0.$$
$$y=xy'-\frac{y'^2}{1+y'}$$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).
$$y=xy'+f(y')$$